# perform join using EF5 and a Table-Valued Function (TVF)?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I have tried this in EF 4.3 to no avail.
EF5 (in conjunction with .NET 4.5) now supports TVFs.
So in theory this new EF5 feature would save me a whole load of work if the following were possible.

SQL Query;

```
SELECT O.*
FROM dbo.Orders O
INNER JOIN dbo.SecurityTVF(@Name)   S   ON  S.UserID=O.UserID
```

Equivalent EF5 Query - possible?;

```
using (var context = new DSN())
{
    // Return all the orders - limited by those the current user has placed
    var orders = from o in context.Orders
                 join s in context.SecurityTVF(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name) on o.UserID equals s.UserID
                 select o;
}
```

I don't really want to go upgrade all the software at this stage, unless the above is going to be possible in EF5... anyone tried this yet?

NB: The official documentation is a bit basic, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859577.aspx

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible with .NET 4.5, EF 5.0 and Visual Studio 2012.